# iFrame with javascript

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, jquery

I would like to summarize my problem: I need to obscure the source of the iframe from the source code. To do this I have to use javascript code and obfuscator. By inserting the following obfuscated code it does not show me anything but the outline of the iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('iframe').attr('src','https://google.com')
;}
</script>
<p><iframe id="iframe" width="1200" height="600"> </iframe></p>
```

Is my code wrong or is it that Joomla that fails to load the source via javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your Javascript contains an error so it won't run at all. Specifically you're missing a `)` near the end.

Secondly, Google send a `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header, basically meaning you cannot run Google pages in an iframe unless your page is hosted on the same domain as Google itself, which is isn't.

Thirdly, I think you're misunderstood by the word `obfuscate`. It basically means unreadable code. Just because you're loading the iframe source via Javascript, does not mean people won't be able to see the code.
This is an example of proper obfuscation: https://obfuscator.io/

and this is a working example if what you were trying to achieve in your question:

https://jsfiddle.net/Le3tcu0b/

Comment: Thank you so much for answering me! as far as the google link is concerned, I know it but it's just an example. I tried to put the code on a joomla article without having obfuscated and does not show me anything the same.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the browser console? Are you sure the `script` tag isn't blacklisted by the editor?

Comment: It gives me this error: `test-generico:119 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at test-generico:119
test-generico:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: JCaption is not defined
    at test-generico:22
    at dispatch (d762053454413417c0903edb0ae51d0c_0.js:1)
    at v.handle (d762053454413417c0903edb0ae51d0c_0.js:1)`
On joomla I am using JCE editor that I have updated and I have applied the consent to execute javascript from the editor settings.

Comment: I'm sorry for interfering a bit, I just placed the missing closing bracket in the code and formatted the code for better readability...

Comment: the closing semicolon was also at the wrong place... so of course this code was not running at all.

Comment: @Zollie - Readbility improvements are fine as edits, but fixing code in the initial question should not be done. One of the reasons why the code wasn't working in the first place was due to a missing `)` which you've fixed in the OP

Comment: @IonDumitras Try replacing `$` with `jQuery` in the code and see if that helps. The other errors are unrelated to this.

Comment: @Lodder - yes, I'm sorry, I thought the same (it was just so bad to see it that way for me :) ), The system popped that up for me to approve an edit on the question... so I just redo that to the original state of the code... :)

Comment: @Zollie next time use the system's Rollback edit feature

Comment: @mickmackusa - yes, that’s how I should’ve done that. Next time I’ll give more attention to these things.

Comment: I try to be obfuscated now here :)

Comment: @Lodder Thank you so much, just replaced $ with jQuery if the iframe is loaded normally. Only problem that even if I use obfuscator at the end the link is seen when loading the source.